# How can I reset the aspect ratio in Lightroom 4?

Tags: lightroom-4

Hi why is there a change in aspect ratio in library and develop mode ?

library - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YyoH.png

develop - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCAUP.jpg

How do I reset it to get back to the original aspect ratio so that I can see it better and work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you did, Lightroom makes it easy to reset. Open the History stack and just click on the lowest item which is *Import* IIRC. That shows you the original image. Any change you make at that point will be performed on the original image and that will clear the rest of the history.

EDIT:

If this fails and you are OK to reset it. I'd recommend you just delete it from Lightroom (only and not on disk) and re-import it. It might save you time digging through settings which may have caused this.

Comment: No that dint work : here is the screenshot... it still remains the same : http://i.imgur.com/AbgwRgt.jpg

Comment: @abhilashsukumari Does it happen with just this image or all or several? If neither all nor just one, what would be common among those?

Comment: Just this Image :(

Comment: @abhilashsukumari - If you are OK to reset it. I'd recommend you just delete it from Lightroom (only and not on disk) and re-import it. It might save you time digging through settings which may have caused this.

Comment: The solution should be put into the answer so it can be voted up and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to try, but if it happens again, change the Navigator from "Fit" to Fill or 1:1 and back again.